# SPServices is not working in one environment and working in one SharePoint environment/

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, spservices, custom-javascript

We deployed solution in one SharePoint server, and uploaded the js file after solution deployed. we are getting the following errors on debugging JS.

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'SPServices'

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'SPGetCurrentUser' of undefined or null reference.

Or is there any other issue.

Thanks for the response in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a tenant domain. To access web parts you cannot be an external user.

Do you have SPServices installed or referenced on the web part? I have issues like this and it is when the libraries are not being read. You need the jQuery library, https://jqueryui.com/download/  and SPService https://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/.

It will look something like this:

```
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: We already have SPServices in Visual Studio code and we are adding the code in hive folder. Can you help me with this.